# How to specify the current user vairable name in the path to a file

Tags: python, file, variables, copy

I want to copy a file placed in the folder of the current user logged in.

so i have searched how to identify the user that is logged in, so i can point to the user folder in windows.
for example i want to copy the file "hi.txt" in the Microsoft folder.

```
"C:\Documents and Settings\john\Application Data\Microsoft\hi.txt"
```

so when i move the script to another OS, i want it to identify the relevant user.

so i saw the option :

```
import getpass

user = getpass.getuser()
```

so now i want to place the variable "user" instead of pointing to "john"
but how can i put a variable in the string of my path?

Thanks in advance, i'm new to programming and new to python.

Answer (score 5):

The home directory of the current user can be expanded using [`os.path.expanduser()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser).  To open the file `"whatever"` in the current user's home directory, use

```
with open(os.path.expanduser("~/whatever")) as f:
    # whatever
```

Comment: So if i want to pass to a variable the path string?

Answer (score 1):

The follow codes are copied from python shell, perhaps it can help you.

```
>>> import getpass
>>> user = getpass.getuser()
>>> user
'yang'
>>> path = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\%s\\Application Data\\Microsoft\\hi.txt" % user
>>> print path
C:\Documents and Settings\yang\Application Data\Microsoft\hi.txt
>>>
```

use the % operator.

Comment: Just for your information if you prefix your windows path with an r (eg r"C:\Documents") you don't have to escape every backslash yourself. Extremely useful when working on Windows and copying paths around.